# Direct Mapped Cache

Tags: memory, cache, addressing

A computer using a direct-mapped cache has \$2^{24}\$ words of main memory and a cache of 256 blocks. Each cache block contains 64 words.

1. How many blocks of main memory are there?
2. What is the format of a memory address as seen by the cache? (What are the sizes of the tag, block, and word fields?)
3. To which block will the memory reference 0x01BD36 map?

Comment: You had a question here, which I answered, and you accepted the answer. Now you have edited the question, and it is a totally different question! That is not the way you should use this site.

Comment: I left a note (to avoid this), which the the moderator removed. The original question suffered a typo from the questionnaire it came from. I edited the post to the correct question it should really be to keep it on topic. The proper answer to the original question posted was "professor's typo". Pardon the confusion. I can only upvote your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Kaz Hi, would you kindly clean this question from all the comments and answer from the (unfortunate) typo error? I also believe this is not exactly a duplicate, because it contains other questions apart from the tag, block, and word bits. Hoping for your consideration.

Comment: If you want you can answer your own question, but editing it is not the right way to do so. Please post an answer, and you can accept it.

Comment: I'm very confused by the history of this question. What is going on here? Voting to close, try again in another question.

Comment: The comments have become indeed confusing. I posted the solutions for this post. Should a moderator feel the need to clean the comments section to clear confusion, please do so. Thanks.

Comment: The other question is enough of a duplicate that this one is not necessary. The site doesn't need numerous questions about cache addressing. Furthermore, the subject matter is only marginally topical to electronic design. Computers don't have to be electronic to have caches. Nothing in your question depends on in what technology the cache is implemented, or factors like speed and purity of signals, and it is not about a specific problem that you're facing with your embedded processor.

Comment: I've posted my own answer and accepted it as advised by the moderator. This query is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions:

1. B = Capacity (C) / block size (b)
   B = 2<sup>24</sup> / 2<sup>6</sup>
   B = 2<sup>18</sup> blocks
2. 2<sup>24</sup> = 24-bit address
   T = 24 - (8 + 6) = 24 - 14 = 10 bits
   B = 256 = 2<sup>8</sup> = 8 bits
   W = 64 = 2<sup>6</sup> = 6 bits
3. 0x01BD36 = 0000000110 11110100 110110<sub>2</sub>
   T = 0000000110<sub>2</sub> (10 bits)
   B = 11110100<sub>2</sub> (8 bits)
   W = 110110<sub>2</sub> (6 bits)

   B = 11110100<sub>2</sub> = 244

   Therefore, 0x01BD36 maps to cache block 244.

Answer (score 1):

For X addresses, where 2^N+1 < X < 2^N, N address lines are not sufficient, N+1 is sufficient (but leaves some address space unused). Hence you have no other option than to use (at least) N+1 address lines.